# What tool could friendly report unit tests according to a json or other output?

Tags: .net, software-testing, unit-tests

I'm using coverlet and .Net Core to develop an API, I started to make unit tests (the only tool I've found for .Net Core was coverlet).

I got the coverage, but I only can get files like `json`, `xml` etc.

I would need to see an HTML or something more visual to be able to handle the tests fastly.

Here is my current output on terminal:

```
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Module                    | Line   | Branch | Method |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| rede-merchants-cancel-api | 12,5%  | 0%     | 16,7%  |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

And a part of the output with `json`:

```
"Program.cs": {
  "Program": {
    "System.Void rede_merchants_cancel_api.Program::Main(System.String[])": {
      "Lines": {
        "9": 0,
        "10": 0,
        "11": 0
      },
      "Branches": []
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost rede_merchants_cancel_api.Program::BuildWebHost(System.String[])": {
      "Lines": {
        "14": 0,
        "15": 0,
        "16": 0
      },
      "Branches": []
    }
  }
}
```

There is some tool to make that?

Comment: Why the downvote? That's ok about that, but I'd like to know what to improve.

Comment: Thanks, reopened as it's no longer off-topic. Not my area of proficience though, so I cannot tell what might be missing (the down-voter might have an idea). Good luck then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer, what I tried first was using the [docker-dotnet-sonarscanner](https://github.com/burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner), but I couldn't setting that very well, then I adopted another approach:

1. Install [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet), which gives me the code coverage for .Net Core in many formats: `json` (default), `lcov`, `opencover` and `cobertura`.
2. Install a plugin for VSCode where I could see the code coverage in a nice way, and its name is [coverage-gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters).
3. Use the command available on the coverlet docs to output the code coverage with the `lcov` format, to be able to use with the plugin of code coverage.
4. Extra - Use a plugin to run the tests on VSCode instead of CLI (I didn't tried that), with [.Net Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer) it's possible but I think it would be necessary to change the command to be able to output what you need.